# Plotly with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, plotly.js

- I have installed plotly using `npm i plotly.js`
- Added the line `import 'plotly.js/dist/plotly'` to my plotly import file
- Then in webpack followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/BUILDING.md) to bundle the files client side.
- Added in a custom js file to test plotly
- Then added in the plotly scripts to my html page with the package coming first then my custom js.

However I get the error message `ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined`.

To test I was using the javascript code from [this example](https://plotly.com/javascript/responsive-fluid-layout/). I can get it working when I save the file locally found on the plotly site [here](https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js) but not with webpack.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? My other packages seem to work fine and I can see plotly.js has successfully been added into the relvent folder client side.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    uibundles: path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend.js'),
    plotly: path.resolve(__dirname, 'plotlyimport.js'),
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js')
  },
  plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: '../css/[name].css',
  })],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'ify-loader'
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use webpack `resolve` ([here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve)) to add the details

Could you try this:

```
resolve: {
     modules: ['node_modules'],
     extensions: ['.js']
},
```

Comment: Sorry I should add that plotly is getting resolved and being saved into the correct directory, my thoughts is it seems to be an issue with the javascript that is getting generated.

Comment: @theJ I wonder if it is due to the capitalization. Based on error `ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined`, I believe you are trying to access "Plotly". But in your `webpack.config.js` entry, the package is resolved to "plotly". Could you try to capitalize the P and see if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to use *webpack externals* to solve this issue.

webpack externals : Prevent bundling of certain imported packages and instead retrieve these external dependencies at runtime.

For example, to include plotly from a CDN instead of bundling it:

index.html

```
<script src="../plotly.js"></script>
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    plotly: 'plotly'
  }
};
```

This leaves any dependent modules unchanged, i.e. the code shown below will still work:

```
var Plotly = require('plotly.js');

..
..
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, config );
```

Refer to [webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) for more details.